# Ant throws NoClassDefFoundError when executing running Junit Target, runs fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

Only having used SBT and Maven previously, I am unable to get Ant to work with Junit tests.I have looked at countless other similar issues related to this on SO but have been unable to resolve. These tests run fine when run internally from Eclipse. The test classes that are failing are throwing "NoClassDefFoundError"

My Ant build.xml snippet:

```
    <project name="APPbuild" basedir=".">

    <description>APP build</description>

    <property name="webinf" location="WEB-INF" />
    <property name="src" location="${webinf}${file.separator}src" />
    <property name="src.test" location="${webinf}${file.separator}test" />
    <property name="classes" location="${webinf}${file.separator}classes" />
    <property name="classes.test" location="${webinf}${file.separator}classestest" />
    <property name="classes.instrument" location="${webinf}${file.separator}classesinstrument" />
    <property name="dist" location="..${file.separator}dist" />
    <property name="archiveFile" location="${dist}${file.separator}app.war" />
    <property name="classpath" location="${webinf}${file.separator}lib" />
    <property name="classpath.test" location="${webinf}${file.separator}resources${file.separator}test" />
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="${webinf}${file.separator}junit" />
<path id="libpath">
        <fileset dir="${classpath}">
            <include name="**${file.separator}*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="libpath_test">
        <fileset dir="${classpath}">
            <include name="**${file.separator}*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${classpath.test}">
            <include name="**${file.separator}*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${src}" />
        <pathelement location="${src.test}" />
        <pathelement location="${classes}" />
        <pathelement location="${classpath}" />
        <pathelement location="${classpath.test}" />
        <pathelement location="${webinf}${file.separator}resources${file.separator}test${file.separator}junit-4.7.jar" />
    </path>
<target name="compile" depends="init,prepare">
        <javac classpathref="libpath" debug="on" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile_test" depends="compile">
        <javac classpathref="libpath_test" srcdir="${src.test}" destdir="${classes}" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

<target name="test" depends="compile_test">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junit fork="true" printsummary="true" showoutput="true">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath refid= "test.classpath" />
            <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${classes}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <echo>${classpath}</echo>
        <echo>${classpath.test}</echo>
        <echo>${classes}</echo>
        <echo>${classes.test}</echo>
    </target>
```

Error for one of the Test Class

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Another

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dbunit/database/IDatabaseConnection
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Any pointers or hints at this point would be great.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error?

Comment: I have added the full error stack Junit is throwing from Ant.

Comment: Seems that you configured dbunit and java-mail in eclipse but not added it to the classpath of the ant build. By the way you don't need ${file.separator} in ant. ant translates the paths it self.

Comment: Hank, thank you. I am confused, in my test.classpath refid, i do have         <pathelement location="${classpath}" />
<pathelement location="${classpath.test}" /> defined in which classpath refers to all the application jars. classpath.test refers to all the testing jars(junit, hamcrest, etc)

Comment: When you refer to directory,  I think,  it must be <pathelement path="${classpath}"/> and when it's a file <pathelement location="${file}"/>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hank's hints regarding the pathelement/location led me to find that the following worked.

Changing the test.classpatch id to the following now picks up all necessary application and test lib's.

```
<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${classes}" />
    <fileset dir="${classpath}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${classpath.test}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Thanks so much Hank!